# SpeedTest cli suggest wrong servers

Tags: download-speed

At the time of executing this command.

> speedtest --list

Speed test offers 10 servers with a location other than the current location of the server.
Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

See the help (`speedtest --help`)

```
 --server SERVER       Specify a server ID to test against. Can be supplied  multiple times
```

You can find id's [here](https://williamyaps.github.io/wlmjavascript/servercli.html) so you can see if you can find another nearer. Most of those id's are connected to apps and websites and not available to the command line version.

> other than the current location of the server

What does that have to do with a speedtest? It is an average time of a download and upload of a fixed sized file. Where it comes from does not matter, only the 1st hop (from your server to your ISP) matters.

Comment: Thank you so much